# Is kafka good for fanning out to millions of consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, google-cloud-pubsub

If I have a usecase that I want different consumers to get same copy of message, and I don't need new consumer that just joined receive days old data just 10 min worth of data. Is kafka a good tool to do so if I set retention to 10min, and have all consumer use assign() instead of subscribe()?

To be more specific

```
millions of consumer

Each consumer should be able to get a copy of latest message , and better if it can start from message 10min ago since joined -> each consumer can't be in same consumer group

Existing consumer drop frequently, and reenters frequently

New consumer enters frequently
```

Is kafka a good tool for this usecase? I can see multiple bottle necks here

1. since kafka parallelism is define through partitions, each partition is responsible for sending data to millions of consumer,  this is a bottleneck that cannot scale?
2. offset management, millions of consumer means millions of offset, and millions of concurrent commit, kafka is good with hundreds of consumer committing concurrently, but each consumer have sequential commit (consumer 1 will commit msg 1, 2, 3... .etc) but can kafka (zookeeper) handle millions of concurrent commit? What if I don't need at least once or at most once guarantee? can I turn off commit and just always get msg from latest offset?

If kafka can't handle million consumer fanout, what is the max fanout it can handle?

The alternative is to use fanout exchange in rabbitmq or managed service like google pub/sub, is that a better choice?

Comment: 1) Consumers poll from whatever partitions they're assigned. Data isn't sent to them. Millions of concurrent readers might exhaust your network card or hard drive / OS file handles (sockets). 2) No, commits aren't necessary in kafka 3) Retention isn't set per message

Comment: I would strongly suggest RabbitMQ , for practical purposes for such large scales , simplicity of feature set is a big plus. Your use case does not appear to be complex which warrants rebalancing feature , intelligently done fanout exchanges can serve your purpose from RabbitMQ https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2023/03/native-mqtt/